# Cannot setSurfaceTexture to a released SurfaceTexture

Tags: java, android, textureview

In `onPause` I store a surfaceTexture to a class variable `mTextureViewSurface` using `mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture()`

In `onResume` I do:

```
if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
    ...
} else {
    mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
}
```

And in there I attempt to restore the surfaceTexture

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
        if (mTextureViewSurface != null) {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTexture(mTextureViewSurface);
        }
}
```

However I get the error 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot setSurfaceTexture to a released SurfaceTexture` which comes from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/TextureView.java#725

I'm tired and probably just need to go to sleep, however I thought I'd ask here because I'm probably just glossing over something.

What's the correct way of handling released surfaceTextures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value from [`onSurfaceTextureDestroyed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener.html#onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(android.graphics.SurfaceTexture)) is significant -- you need to return `false` to prevent the system from destroying it (and you need to manually release it eventually).

You can find a working example of code that retains SurfaceTextures across a "fast" Activity pause/resume (e.g. for an orientation change) in the [Grafika "double decode"](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/DoubleDecodeActivity.java) activity.

Note there's a bug in Android <= 4.4 that can make it tricky to do right -- if you try to reattach in `onSurfaceTextureAvailable()` it'll appear to work but won't get updates.

Comment: Dude, THANK YOU SO MUCH! I just revisited this now, and it works perfectly!